# ScrollView in text from url

Tags: android, url, scrollview

So i am trying to show this clan roster in my app with this code in the activity

```
        /* We will show the data we read in a TextView. */ 
        TextView tv = new TextView(this); 

        /* Will be filled and displayed later. */ 
        String myString = null; 
        try { 
             /* Define the URL we want to load data from. */ 
            //http://androidtest.host.org/roster.txt
             URL myURL = new URL( 
                       "http://androidtest.host.org/roster.txt"); 
             /* Open a connection to that URL. */ 
             URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection(); 

             /* Define InputStreams to read 
              * from the URLConnection. */ 
             InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream(); 
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 

             /* Read bytes to the Buffer until 
              * there is nothing more to read(-1). */ 
             ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50); 
             int current = 0; 
             while((current = bis.read()) != -1){ 
                  baf.append((byte)current); 
             } 

             /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */ 
             myString = new String(baf.toByteArray()); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
             /* On any Error we want to display it. */ 
             myString = e.getMessage(); 
        } 
        /* Show the String on the GUI. */ 
        tv.setText(myString); 
        this.setContentView(tv); 
    }
}
```

But how do i enable scrolling because it is not using the layout i made: Roster.xml?
So how do i get it working so that i can scroll to the names that are even further down on the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a scrollview as

```
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
```

then add your TextView to this ScrollView

```
    sv.addView(tv);
```

then set this scrollview as ContentView like

```
    this.setContentView(sv);
```

put your code as following:

```
//     take here a scrollview    ///////////////////////////////////////
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

    /* We will show the data we read in a TextView. */ 
    TextView tv = new TextView(this); 

    /* Will be filled and displayed later. */ 
    String myString = null; 
    try { 
         /* Define the URL we want to load data from. */ 
        //http://androidtest.host.org/roster.txt
         URL myURL = new URL( 
                   "http://androidtest.host.org/roster.txt"); 
         /* Open a connection to that URL. */ 
         URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection(); 

         /* Define InputStreams to read 
          * from the URLConnection. */ 
         InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream(); 
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 

         /* Read bytes to the Buffer until 
          * there is nothing more to read(-1). */ 
         ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50); 
         int current = 0; 
         while((current = bis.read()) != -1){ 
              baf.append((byte)current); 
         } 

         /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */ 
         myString = new String(baf.toByteArray()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
         /* On any Error we want to display it. */ 
         myString = e.getMessage(); 
    } 
    /* Show the String on the GUI. */ 
    tv.setText(myString); 
//    add your textview to scrollview    /////////////////////////////////////
        sv.addView(tv);

//    NOW set scrollview as your contentview    /////////////////////////////
        this.setContentView(sv); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please correct my code? I cant really figure out how to use the code you posted :) And is there a way to set background color?

Comment: I've adde scrollview to your code; then added textview to the scrollview and seted that scrollview as contentview. Jus try this code, i think it will mostly work.

Comment: Please tell me where to put the code, i dont understand. And can you set a bgcolor?

Comment: Tell me where you have taken your TextView tv = new TextView(this);

Comment: I've edited my old answer and written proper code, jus take that code and check it in yours system

Comment: Thanks for the help! But is there a way to set bgcolor of this activity?

Comment: if suggested code work for you, you should accept it, then other users will give you answer next time, if you doesn't accept answer, no-one will help you another time. (ya, i know, but i was jus giving simple advice...)

Comment: you can use sv.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);